# How to modify bibliography sorting with multibib?

Tags: bibtex, sorting, multibib

I'm using `multibib` to generate a list of publications for my cv (using `moderncv`). The problem is that the entries are sorted alphabetically, whereas I'd like them to be sorted by year, with the newest on top.

There are some answers here on how to do it with natbib, but I had no success in doing it with `multibib` and the documentation is of no help as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Use this style: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/plainyr.bst or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/plainyr

Comment: @HarishKumar it almost works. It does sort it by year, but how can I reverse the order? I'd like the have the newest references on top.

Comment: Use https://github.com/jberger/Curriculum_Vita/blob/master/plainyr-rev.bst

Answer (score 0):

The `plainyr-ref.bst` works for me. However, within a year, it sorts by author names in reverse order. How can I change this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).